# Loading Mustache Templates with Webpack

Tags: javascript, mustache, commonjs, webpack

My team and I are currently in the process of migrating a rather large project from AMD + RequireJS to CommonJS + Webpack. We love the tools Webpack provides and think CommonJS is the direction the community is heading: jumping on the bandwagon you could say.

What's an effective way to utilize webpack to automatically load and bundle our .mustache template files? Currently we have a watch script that uses [xport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xport) to bundle all .mustache files in our project folder into a single js file in the format:

```
var files = {};
files['path/to/file'] = '<div>{{content}}</div>';
files['path/to/other/file'] = '<span>{{stuff}}</span>';
...
```

We could totally keep using this... 
**What's particularly convenient about our current solution is that we don't have to specifically reference our templates in the project when we make a new template.** Because the script is just watching the folder, the dictionary gets updated and we can use another library to take the string and make it into a usable template function.

**Whats the goal then?**
I'm curious if there's a way to go from templates in our folder -> functions we can use in code without having to specifically require the files into the project. And our current solution goes outside of webpack (unless of course there's a way to hook in) which is annoying because we don't want 2 watch scripts. I've looked into [loaders](http://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) but these seem to be 1 to 1 source file -> output file vs many to 1 which is what's great about our current solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could build something fitting your needs on top of [require.context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html). Point that to your template directory and it will provide you an API to access the templates within. You can combine this approach with [mustache-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache-loader).